# Explanation to solution of this Valid Palindrome II Problem

Tags: python

The problem:
Given a string s, return true if the s can be palindrome after deleting at most one character from it.

My original attempt was as below, and couldn't get through every test cases:

```
class Solution:
    def validPalindrome(self, s: str) -> bool:
        if s==s[::-1]: 
            return True
        left, right=0, len(s)-1
        while left < right:
            if s[left]==s[right]:
                left+=1
                right-=1
            else:
                s1=s[0:left]+s[left+1:]
                s2=s[:right]+s[right+1:]
                **if (s1!=s1[::-1]) or (s2!=s2[::-1]):
                    return False
                else: return True**
        return True
```

But it went ok after I slightly updated:

```
class Solution:
    def validPalindrome(self, s: str) -> bool:
        if s==s[::-1]: 
            return True
        left, right=0, len(s)-1
        while left < right:
            if s[left]==s[right]:
                left+=1
                right-=1
            else:
                s1=s[0:left]+s[left+1:]
                s2=s[:right]+s[right+1:]
                if (s1==s1[::-1]) or (s2==s2[::-1]):
                    return True
                else: return False
        return True
```

Can anyone explain why??

Answer (score 1):

Take the word `abccdba`. It becomes a palindrome if you remove the letter `d` at position `4`.

When you run your program:

```py
s1=s[0:left]+s[left+1:]="abcdba" # Not a palindrome
s2=s[:right]+s[right+1:]="abccba" # A palindrome
```

You can see that `s2` IS a palindrom while `s1` is NOT.
Thus your code:

```py
if (s1!=s1[::-1]) or (s2!=s2[::-1]):
```

Is equivalent to:

```py
if True or False:
```

Which is `True`. Hence you output `False`

You need to change it to:

```py
if (s1!=s1[::-1]) and (s2!=s2[::-1]):
```

Comment: ohh thanks. I missed the fact that either s1 or s2 is a palindrome I should return True instead.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>Do you really need all that code?</strike> Seems like you do.

```py
wordA = 'abcdef'
wordB = 'aaookaa'
def can_be_a_palindrome(word):
    # If it's already a palindrome
    if word == word[::-1]:
        return True
    # Check if removing a single character will make it a palindrome
    for i in range(len(word)):
        wordWithDeletedChar = word[:i] + word[i+1:]
        # Uncomment to show all possible results of removing a single character
        # print(wordWithDeletedChar)
        if wordWithDeletedChar == wordWithDeletedChar[::-1]:
            return True
    return False

can_be_a_palindrome(wordA) # False
can_be_a_palindrome(wordB) # True
```

I found https://leetcode.com/problems/valid-palindrome-ii/ and this code would pass the 3 proposed words.

```py
can_be_a_palindrome('aba') # True
can_be_a_palindrome('abca') # True
can_be_a_palindrome('abc') # False
```

Comment: This solution is less time efficient than OP's sliding window, and exceeds LC's time limits near the end of their test cases where it throws a gigantic string at you.

Comment: I see, I don't have a LC account so I could check that.

Answer (score 0):

```py
if (s1!=s1[::-1]) or (s2!=s2[::-1]):
   return False
else: return True
```

It has to do with your use of the `or` operator. If s1 is a palindrome and s2 is not, `True` or `False` is `True` and as such the function returns `False`.

If you change the operator to `and` it outputs the correct value for all test cases.